# How to inject a generic interface with connection parameters?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-cosmosdb

I'm fighting for few hours and can't come up with a solution.
I want a simplest possible solution to reuse the code I have for AzureCosmosDatabaseClient class by just changing database and container parameters (currently taken from options).

```
    public interface IAzureCosmosDatabaseClient<T>
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> Query(string query);
        Task Update(string id, object item);
    }
```

```
    public class AzureCosmosDatabaseClient<T> : IAzureCosmosDatabaseClient<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AzureCosmosDatabaseClient<T>> _logger;
        private readonly IOptions<CosmosOptions> _options;
        private readonly CosmosClient _cosmosClient;
        private readonly Database _database;
        private readonly Container _container;

        public AzureCosmosDatabaseClient(ILogger<CosmosDbClient<T>> logger, CosmosOptions options;)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _options = options.Value;
            _cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(_options.cosmosEndpointUrl, _options.cosmosPrimaryKey);
            _database = _cosmosClient.GetDatabase(_options.cosmosDatabase);
            _container = _database.GetContainer(_options.cosmosContainer);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Query(string queryText)
        {
            //code 
            //_cosmosClient.DoSomething()

        }

        public async Task Update(string id, T item)
        {
            //code
            //_cosmosClient.DoSomething()
        }
```

So how can I pass `cosmosDatabase` and `cosmosContainer` as a part of dependency injection of `IAzureCosmosDatabaseClient` into other class/service? - the point is that in the single Azure Cosmos I have multiple databases and containers that I need to handle but all of them implements same methods/actions.

Comment: If you want multiple databases in the same app, you'll need a factory method *somewhere*. Maybe based around `IOptionsSnapshot<CosmosOptions> options; options.Get("<dbname>")`? or `.Get(typeof(T).Name)`...?

Comment: Thanks but I need more guidance on that factory method... any link appreciated.

Comment: Let's say you have a container to handle location data. You could create an interface `ILocationService` that inherits`IAzureCosmosDatabaseClient<T>`. Your implementation can then inherit those services and since you can inject the service only once they can be differentiated.

Comment: @NotFound Then I would need to re-implement Query and Update methods which I want to avoid as they will be the same for all cosmos databases/containers.

Comment: @user18154574 No you don't. `AzureCosmosDatabaseClient<T>` can inherit all those services. So you have the same implementation over all interfaces.